# New Schengen visa or extension of old Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas, conferences

I have a multiple-entry Schengen visa (Tourist/Turismo) from the Italian consulate until the 8th of July, 2018 (valid from 16 June 2018) since I went to a conference in Italy from the USA (I am studying in the US on F1 visa). I need to go to Germany from the 20th to the 25th of August for another conference.

Here are my questions.

1. Do I have to go to the German consulate (for me Atlanta) since it will be my only destination country in Europe?
2. Do I apply for a new Schengen visa or ask for an extension of the visa (if such a process exists) depending on my date of appointment being before or after the 8th of July?
3. If I need an extension, do I have to go to the Italian consulate I went to or to the German consulate?

Links supporting your answers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to go to the German consulate (for me Atlanta) since it will be my only destination country in Europe?

Yes.

> Do I apply for a fresh Schengen visa or ask for an extension of the visa (if such a process exists) depending on my date of appointment being before or after the 8th of July?

There is no extension process.  You will apply for a new visa.

> If I need an extension, do I have to go to the Italian consulate I went to or to the German consulate?

You do not need to do anything with the Italian consulate.

As [o.m.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27778/o-m) notes in a [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117350/new-schengen-visa-or-extension-of-old-schengen-visa/117351?noredirect=1#comment286499_117351):

> It may be possible that you do not have to go to the German consulate in person because your biometrics will be on file.

Comment: It may be possible that you do not have to go to the German consulate in person because your biometrics will be on file.